# How can we add additional constructor when Builder pattern is being used

Tags: java, lombok

I want to add an additional construction which takes `Exception, status` as arguments and construct `message as = exception.getMessage();`

How can we do this given we use the lombok Builder pattern

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Foo {
    private String message;
    private Integer status;
        
    @Builder.Default
    private LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

Comment: Why not use `Foo.builder().status(status).message(exception.getMessage()).build();` ?

Comment: @GauthamM That gets really unwieldy for no useful purpose fast; the Amazon Java SDK 2 is a gigantic mess of it.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Sorry, but I did not get your point.

Comment: Do you just want an additional constructor, or do you also want the builder to have a setter that takes an exception as argument?

Comment: just an additional constructor, definitely not a setter

Answer (score 0):

Use `Builder` annotation at your custom constructor as shown below:

If you want to use same `builder()` method for all constructions:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Foo {
    private String message;
    private Integer status;
    private LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();

    @Builder
    public Foo(Integer status, String message, Exception exception) {
        this.status = status;

        if(Objects.nonNull(exception)) {
            this.message = exception.getMessage();
        } else {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Foo foo1 = Foo.builder().exception(new Exception("Message")).status(100).build();

Foo foo2 = Foo.builder().message("Test").status(100).build();
```

If you want to use altogether different constructions:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Foo {
    private String message;
    private Integer status;

    @Builder.Default
    private LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();

    @Builder(builderClassName = "FooBuilder1", builderMethodName = "builder1")
    public Foo(Integer status, Exception exception) {
        this.status = status;

        if(Objects.nonNull(exception)) {
            this.message = exception.getMessage();
        }

        this.timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

while creating object:

```
Foo foo1 = Foo.builder1().exception(new Exception("message")).status(100).build();
Foo foo2 = Foo.builder().message("Test").status(100).build();
```

Note: Two `@Builder` annotations won't work unless you use different builder class names & builder methods as shown in above example.

Comment: Two `@Builder` annotations won't work unless you use different `builderClassName`s.

Comment: @JanRieke, Updated answer :)